# Force Soap/WCF to use HTTP not TCP protocol

Tags: http, wcf, soap, tcp, wireshark

I have a client consuming 2 Web/WCF services, both of type SOAP. Lets call them ServiceA and ServiceB.
ServiceA works fine, but ServiceB not so much: I get error message that states that CData (text data) in respons message creates a failure in XML parser/deserializer when receiving respons from ServiceB. (I suspect that the CData may contain an error message from ServiceB).

Now, I have installed WireShark to investigate the raw data being sent and received.
Wireshark gives very good info on the working ServiceA connection: Data is transferred using the HTTP protocol (with TLS 1.2 on top to make it secure), and I see both requests and responses very well.

However, for the troublesome connection to the other ServiceB, all connections use TCP, not HTTP. The message content of the TCP messages are not readable in WireShark.

1. First: Why is TCP used instead of HTTP for ServiceB ??    (Both Bindings and Endpoints are very similar in my client code, and both use "basicHttpsBinding").
2. Is it possible to force the ServiceB SOAP messages to go over HTTP instead of TCP, thereby making the WireShark output readable?

Any comments very much appreciated.

Comment: BasicHttpsBinding uses http for transmission. If possible, can you provide some configuration information?

Answer (score 0):

for those reading the above post:

It turns out that there is an intermediate proxy between my client and ServiceB.
It seems as if this proxy (to me, surprisingly) performs an XML de-serialization. And if the proxy tries de-serialising an exception from ServerB, a nasty "Can not de-serialize CData" is thrown by the proxy, and handed to the client.  Resulting in the client (me) getting very confused.

(Yes, the lesson is that no services must throw exceptions.  All exceptions must be caught, handled, and a controlled error in a predefined field must be given to the caller).